# how to count number of rising edges in a clock cycle using python code?

Tags: python

I'm new to python coding. I m trying to write a python function which counts the number of posedge of a clock and return the final count value.

thank you for your time!

I have written something like below, please correct me:

```
from admit.util.peakfinder.PeakDetect import PeakDetect
import numpy as np
import time
from detect_peaks import detect_peaks


@always(clk.posedge)
def freq_meas():
    num_posedge_cnt =0
    total_time = time.time()

    #detect all peaks
    #pd = peakDetect(y, edge='posedge')
    #pd = peakDetect(edge='posedge')
    pd = detect_peaks(edge='rising', show=true)
    print(pd)
    if not edge:
    #do nothing
    else:
    if edge.lower() in ['rising']:
       num_posedge_cnt += 1
    elapsed = time.time() - total_time
    #freq    = num_posedge_cnt/elapsed
    #return freq

    return num_posedge_cnt
```